# how to connect LVDS signals coming from test equipment to fpga virtex 5 when the design has only input signal Din ?

Tags: input, interface, vhdl, virtex

I would provide din+ to A1 and din- to A2, on pin connector on PM2 module, connecting to FPGA, but I have only 1 input port "din" in top level vhdl design module connected to AG7 pin on FPGA. How to go about connection in UCF file ?

```
PM2 Pin - A1, A2
FPGA pin -AG7, AG6 
FPGA bank VCCO - 2.5v, 2.5v
Pin Function - LVDS pair 100 ohm differential impedance; can also be used as single-ended
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually instantiate the differential input buffer. For Xilinx it will be IBUFDS in the Unisim library. Either modify your port to have two pins for `din` and add the buffer in the existing design or write a simple wrapper that converts the diff. pairs to single-ended and pass that into the current port.

Comment: Thank you .. Have added a wrapper converting the diff. pairs to single ended .. seems like it is working so far